# Passing PHP value to jQuery progressbar

Tags: php, jquery

How to pass the PHP value $sources to the value of progress bar? I am trying to add into session in the below code but fail. Any easy way to get the $sources? Please help.

```
......
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
var score = '<%= session.getAttribute("sources") %>';
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
value: score
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start();
$sources=10;

......
echo '<td>Your answer was correct&nbsp;</td></tr>';
$sources+=1;
......

$_SESSION['sources']=$sources;
?>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: one more question how to call $_SESSION['sources'] after the page all loaded? Can I reload the page to get the latest value of $_SESSION['sources']  ?

Comment: You can reload to get latest $_SESSION variables. if you want to call a $_SESSION variable after page was loaded, it can be done using ajax. SO page refresh doesn't need.

Comment: no idea on ajax : please advice Thank You.
<script>
$(function() {

var score = <?php echo $_SESSION['scores']; ?>;

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "checkscore.php",
  data: score,
  success: 
 
});  


$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({

value: score

});
});
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `session_start()` should be at the top of the page. after starting

   then $_SESSION['sources'] should be set before calling it. otherwise you should check for it's value before printing to web page.
   find below codes and rearrange your script.

   ```
   <?php
   session_start();
   ?>
   ......
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
   <script>
   $(function() {
   var score = <? echo (isset($_SESSION['sources'])) ? $_SESSION['sources'] : ""; ?>;
   $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
   value: score
   });
   });
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <?php

   $sources=10;

   ......
   echo '<td>Your answer was correct&nbsp;</td></tr>';
   $sources+=1;
   ......

   $_SESSION['sources']=$sources;
   ?>
   <div id="progressbar"></div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: If you want to show sources=10 at the initial before answering any question, move your php code snippet in the body to before `var score = <? echo ...` line
and assign strings such as `<td>Your answer was correct....` to variables there and call them when where you wanted to display.

Answer (score 0):

```
var score = '<%= session.getAttribute("sources") %>';
```

The `<%= %>` is java syntax for [scriplets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptlet) , 
additionally it's wrapped in quotes so it is treated as a string literal from javascript. 
Below is the syntactically right way (I don't know if you'll get the right value. That 
depends on your program structure).

```
var sources = <?php echo $_SESSION['sources']; ?>;
```